# How to retrieve PDO result==false?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm converting my mysql_query() calls to PDO but don't understand how to get a *false* result on failure. This is my code:

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY category");  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
```

This is what I'm trying to do but does not work:

```
if($STH==false) {
  foreach($dbh->errorInfo() as $error) {
  echo $error.'<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: when working specifically with `false` or `true` you should always use `===` (= x3) to compare the results.

Comment: @zerkms, I believe the javascript team also thought `==` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using PDO the nature of querying usually goes down like so:

```
try
{
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY category"); //Notice the prepare
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //No need to silent as the errors are catched.

    if($STH === false) //Notice the explicit check with !==
    {
        //Do not run a foreach as its not multi-dimensional array
        $Error = $DBH->errorInfo();

        throw new Exception($Error[2]); //Driver Specific Error
    }
}catch(Exception $e)
{
    //An error accured of some nature, use $e->getMessage();
}
```

you should read [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) very carefully and study the examples.

Comment: I don't understand the above code. Where is the error printed? And what does "throw new Exception($Error[2]);" do? Why key 2?

Comment: Key 2 is the driver specific error, this is the best chance to get a valid explanation of an error if you look at the errorInfo link I had posted it explains all this, the throw the Exception is a way to throw errors, and placing within a try block means that it does not effect the application by showing the error on the screen but gets sent to the catch block so you can log the error and redirect / show error page etc. research Exceptions and Try/Catch blocks for more information - Please read this for Exceptions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thx Robert Try/Catch is new to me, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Try/Catch is available in most languages and is very common with high end applications, but if used right it can be extremely useful such as `throw new ErrorPage(404)` :)